# android: how can I divide a screen exactly in two parts through XML?

Tags: android, screen, tablelayout

In main.xml, I have a table layout that it has two buttons in the first row, and two EditTexts in the second row.

when I run the application, first column in smaller than the other. what should I do to divide the screen equally?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `LinearLayout` enclosing the `TableLayout`, you can set each element to have `android:layout_weight="1"`.  That way, each element (In your case each `EditText` or `Button`) would occupy the same amount of space.